Initializing a variable while indexing a list in python
I am trying to debug some old code and need to understand a specific line of code, but it keeps giving errors so I can't see exactly what is going on. I will simplify it here.
I have two lists: A and B
A = [0,1,2,3]
B = [5,6,7,8]

My question is: Is there any difference between the two snippets of code below?
A[B==0] = 11

or
A[0] = 11

Would initializing list B to 0 while indexing list A be any different than just indexing list A with 0?

There is no difference because B==0 evaluates to False, which is equivalent to 0 which is what is in the second snippet.

while @quamrana's comment is correct, I feel there are potentially a number of misconceptions going on here about assignment, test for equality, list inclusion...

The question "Would initializing list B to 0 while" implies that you think that B==0 is initialization which is not. It is a test for equality that returns True or False.

While your first code works, it's not a good practice as B==0 has no meaningful connection with concept of index in A

This looks like someone meant to use numpy

To answer your question: A[B==0] and A[0] are in this case equivalent, because B==0 is false.
However, you aren't initializing list B to 0, you're comparing it. A[B==0] does not change the value of B. To assign to B in A's indexer, you'd need to use the walrus operator, A[B:=0] (which would also be equivalent to A[0]).
Your question implies or invites misunderstanding as it looks to assert that B==0 is initialization/assignment, so I might suggest reviewing the wording of the question for clarity.

Thank you for clarifying! That answered my question. I definitely misunderstood that A[B==0] is comparing, not initializing.
